# Icon and text to align correctly in custom row layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

How to have a icon and text which appear horizontally to have same height and design? I mean, If you see `Twitter`, they will have `Retweets`, `favorites` and it's count all will align correctly with same height and same width.

Similarly, how should i achieve?

This is my current layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/relative">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="This is some text which used to test. Don&apos;t care this. This will be updated dynamically"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="17dp"
           android:layout_height="17dp"
           android:src="@drawable/favorite"
           android:id="@+id/imageView"
           android:padding="1dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="33"
        android:id="@+id/favcount"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="@color/md_orange_700"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />


        <com.github.curioustechizen.ago.RelativeTimeTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="3 hrs ago"
            android:textSize="13dp"
        android:id="@+id/postedDate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/content"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"

            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/content" />


        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="17dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_time"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/postedDate"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/postedDate" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Current design which have problem in improper height and width (differs in count and icon)

[image]

What size my icon should have?
You can see the heart and and its count doesn't align correctly.

Comment: Use 30 x 30 as Width and Height

Comment: What about the text size? If the width and height are `30sp`, then it will be bigger. BTW does the icon should contain any padding?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both the icon and the count layouts in a horizontal linearlayout. Set both inner layouts to be centered within this layout using:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
```